# Updating only specific image in cloudinary node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, cloudinary

I have a Node Js-Express backend & Cloudinary for image storage, for adding a blog to a database. I have configured it to enter the basic blog details like title, category, images, etc. All the CRUD operations work very well so far.

A blog has multiple images uploaded with it. If a user has to perform an update operation on a given blog, a user can update one or more images in the DB. But since the images are served through Cloudinary storage, the images need to be updated there also. I am a bit stuck on how to associate the update logic for the same with cloudinary.

This is how my **editBlog controller** looks so far:

```
exports.editBlog = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { title, category, content } = req.body;
    const blogImages = req.files; // There might be only single image passed to edit instead of all 3 images (for example) 

    try {
        if (!blogImages) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No images attached!' });
        }

        const updated_images = await Promise.all(blogImages.map((img) => cloudinaryUploadImage(img.path)));

        const updates = {};

        if (req.body) {
            updates.title = title;
            updates.category = category;
            updates.content = content;
            updates.images = updated_images;
        }

        const updated_data = await Blog.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: id },
            {
                $set: updates
            },
            {
                new: true
            }
        );

        if (!updated_data) {
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data does not exist' });
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data updated', result: updated_data });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error', error });
    }
};
```

**cloudinaryUploadImage function:**

```
const cloudinaryUploadImage = async image => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cloudinary.uploader.upload( image , (err, res) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("upload image error")
          resolve({
            img_url: res.secure_url,
            img_id: res.public_id
          }); 
        }
      ) 
  })
}
```

I don't want to fill up my cloudinary storage with unnecessary files. If one image needs to be replaced, then the old image should be deleted from the storage.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me achieve this with just a few tweaks to this code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you are storing in your DB so that you can look up the images on Cloudinary, but if you are storing the `img_id` (which is the public id on Cloudinary), you can use that to override the original image.

If the user is replacing that particular img_id (`public_id`) you can do another upload call that includes the parameters `public_id` and you should also pass in the parameter `invalidate` set as `true` so the request invalidates any previous versions of the asset being replaced. The upload call would look like this:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload( image , public_id: <public_id>, invalidate: true , (err, res) => { . . . }
```

This will replace the image on Cloudinary with the new one, and remove it from any cache at the CDN so your blog will get the latest version.